# In R, generating every possible integral solution to a set of constraints

Tags: r, nonlinear-optimization

In R, I’m trying to generate an array of all feasible *integral* solutions to a set of equality and inequality constraints.  As an example consider the model:

> Model = a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2
>
> Where:
>
> 20 ≤ Model ≤ 30
>
> a=1,
> 2 ≤ b ≤ 3,
> 2 ≤ c ≤ 3,
> 3 ≤ d ≤ 4

I’d like the output to look like this:

```
    [a] [b] [c] [d] [Model]
[1]  1   2   2   4    25
[2]  1   2   3   3    23
[3]  1   2   3   4    30
[4]  1   3   2   3    23
[5]  1   3   2   4    30
[6]  1   3   3   3    28
```

Order doesn't matter. I just want the full set of feasible values. Any packages or help you could point my way?

Comment: @Andrew are a,b,c,d constrained to be integers?

Comment: This is a programming question and belongs on StackOverflow under the [r] tag

Comment: Also, the function you want is `combn`

Comment: Even after revision, there's still no statistical content to this question.